# How to get authentication token from front end while the user is logged in

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt

I am trying to build a simple project where a user can search a movie from an api and add the selected movie to their "/movies" page, after being logged in.
I am using Nodejs, mongodb, express for backend and vanilla javascript for the front end.

When the user is registered or logged-in I am creating a JWT token and adding the token to the database.
My goal is to redirect them to their home page, which is "/user/movies"

- Assume the user has logged in the first time, and it closed the
  website, after some time has passed (not enough to expire the token)
  the user opened the website again and went to "/user/movies" (which
  requires an authentication.)

**My question** is, how would we still **keep authenticated** with the user after **re-visiting**, **how can we reach the token that is previously created?**

When I use postman, I can manually check the token from the database and enter the Authorization token to header and send a post request to validate the user.

But in the browser, how can I reach my previously created token to validate the user again?

- I have tried **localStorage** but, in order to save token to the
  localStorage, I need to take it from the database, but you can't
  change localStorage in the backend.
- I have tried **cookies** with **http-only** flag, but then how can I reach
  the token from the front-end, since http-only, restrains from using javascript

What are my options in order to reach a JWT token from the front-end so that I can keep the user still authenticated, even after they close the website and come back later. (not enough to expire the token)

I am very new to how authentication works If I am making a logical mistake please tell me.

Comment: Send token to frontend in API rresponse, frontend saves it in local storage

Comment: This will be a stupid question I know, but I would be glad if you answer it. I am already sending an HTML with response, How can I send token as well?, If I send token as json then How would my browser know what to render? since I havent send any html.

Comment: Try cookies without http-only.

Answer (score 1):

You need to send JWT token along with your other data as a response from your login API. Once you receive the response on the front end then just store the JWT Token to the localStorage by "localStorage.setItem("token",response.data.token).

Now you can always reference localStorage.getItem("token") to get the token even user close the browser and comeback again. Please do not forget to clear this localStoage by localStorage.removeItem("token") when user logout.

Also please note to not provide any expiry during the JWT token creation otherwise even you store that locally in localStorage then also it will get expire on server side and give "Forbidden error"

Answer (score 0):

- When you authenticate the user for the first time, store the token in the **localStorage**.
- And since localStorage's data never gets deleted on its own, you can listen to the event of **DOMContentLoaded** where you can retrieve the token from the localStorage and authenticate the user with it, when the page is revisited.
- You can read more about localStorage [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)